# MATLAB - Inserting zero rows and columns into matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have written some code that compresses a matrix to remove zero columns and rows, but I can't work out how to reconstruct the original matrix.

Say I have a matrix:

```
A = [ 0 3 0 2 1 0 6
      3 0 0 4 8 0 5
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      2 4 0 0 2 0 1
      1 8 0 2 0 0 7
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      6 5 0 1 7 0 0 ]
```

Here rows/columns 3 and 6 are empty, so my compression function will give the output:

```
A_dash = [ 0 3 2 1 6
           3 0 4 8 5
           2 4 0 2 1
           1 8 2 0 7
           6 5 1 7 0 ]

A_map = [ 1 2 4 5 7]
```

Where `A_map` is a vector mapping the indicies of the rows/columns of `A_dash` to `A`. This means that if `A_map(3) = 4`, then row/column 4 of `A` is the same as row/column 3 of `A_dash` - ie. a row/column of zeroes must be inserted between columns/rows 2 and 3 in `A_dash`

What is the easiest way people can suggest for me to recreate matrix `A` from `A_dash`, using the information in `A_map`?

Here is what I have got so far:

```
% orig_size is original number of columns/rows

c_count = size(A_dash,1);
A = zeros(c_count, orig_size); % c_count rows to avoid dimension mismatch
for ii = 1:c_count
    A(:,A_map(ii)) == A_dash(:,ii);
end
```

This gives me the right result column-wise:

```
A = [ 0 3 0 2 1 0 6
      3 0 0 4 8 0 5
      2 4 0 0 2 0 1
      1 8 0 2 0 0 7
      6 5 0 1 7 0 0 ]
```

However, I'm not sure how i should go about inserting the rows, i suppose i could copy the first `1:i` rows into one matrix, `i:end` rows to a second matrix and concatenate those with a zero row in between, but that feels like a bit of a
clunky solution, and probably not very efficient for large sized matrices..

Otherwise, is there a better way that people can suggest I store the map information? I was thinking instead of storing the mapping between column/row indices, that I just store the indices of the zero columns/rows and then insert columns/rows of zeros where appropriate. Would this be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the indices of the valid rows/columns. Now all you've got to do is put them in a new matrix of zeros the same size as `A`:

```
B=zeros(size(A));
B(A_map,A_map)=A_dash

B =

   0   3   0   2   1   0   6
   3   0   0   4   8   0   5
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   2   4   0   0   2   0   1
   1   8   0   2   0   0   7
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   6   5   0   1   7   0   0
```

Just to check...

```
>> A==B
ans =

   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

`A` and `B` are equal everywhere, so we've reconstructed `A`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much, i thought there would be a simple answer like that, but just couldnt get my head around it..